# How to set a cookie and redirect the user to another url logged in?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to make a simple flask app with a login page that gets the user id and its password, then via python-requests make the login in another url and redirect the user to this external url already logged in with the cookies i'm getting from the external application.

This is my code so far:

```
import requests

@app.route('/')
def index():
   headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
   payload = {'username':'user','password':'pass'}

   url = "https://www.url.com"

   s = requests.Session()
   r = s.post(url + "/login/form", headers=headers, data=payload)

   print(r.cookies)
   return ?
```

when I print the cookies I'm able to see 2 cookies defined by the external webpage. How do I assign them to the user on my flask page and then redirect the user to that url with the cookies set in so they don't need to login again in the external url?

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
resp = make_response(render_template(url))
resp.set_cookie('userID', user)
return resp
```

Comment: Should I pass r.cookies in the "user" in your code?

Comment: something like `for cookie in cookies: resp.set_cookie(cookie.name, cookie.value)`